# OpenGL Reading Pixels from Texture?

Tags: opengl

I need a way to get the pixels of an already existing texture. Similarly to how D3DTexture's LockRect works with ReadOnly and NoSysLock. Some of my textures are also stored in compressed DXT1/3/5 formats, not entirely sure if that would affect anything. If those formats are simply decoded by Opengl and stored as raw pixels instead of in the compression. So would retrieving the pixels guarantee the same format that was used to set the texture with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally you will want to use a PBO for reading pixels. Here's all the information you need on PBOs, click [here](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Pixel_Transfer)

> So would retrieving the pixels guarantee the same format that was used
>   to set the texture with?

It is possible to convert the format and retrieve the pixels at the same time. Look at the format conversion section on the page I linked.

Comment: There are `glGetTexImage` and `glGetCompressedTexImage` from that page, but i don't need to get the entire image data as it says it does, i really only need to get 1 pixel. I can't imagine transferring the entire image from the GPU to system memory being very fast.

Comment: @user3901459 try using in combination with https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/html/glTexSubImage2D.xhtml to get a part of a texture

Comment: @user3901459 although you should know that, a memory read of 1 pixel is going to be just as expensive as a memory read of a lot of pixels most likely

Comment: there is no `glGetTexSubImage2d` that function you linked "sets" the sub pixels of an image. I don't see how it is just as expensive, yes you are doing an asyncronous call to the GPU but the amount of data you transfer will be different. 3 megabytes Vs. 4 bytes.

Comment: @user3901459 you're right, I seem to recall a function that lets you define a texture as a part of another texture but maybe there isn't one. One other idea you can do is create a 1x1 texture, and render to it using a single point that reads from your other texture, then read that into memory. But really, a few megs on an aynschronous texture read is not expensive, that is a much simpler approach.

Comment: @user3901459 also did you see this? https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man2/xhtml/glReadPixels.xml , looks like you can use this to transfer directly into client memory, dont know if it's async or not

Comment: With that method i'd have to render the texture to the framebuffer first, i'll have to run some tests to see which is faster though i think just copying the entire texture will probably be faster than having to go through the process of rendering a pixel to the frame buffer.